# linux - send an email where body is a line of text from a file - date dependent

Tags: linux, cron, sendmail

I would like to add a cron task that sends an email to me@example.com once a day and includes a line of text from a file depending on the date as the message body.

My file.txt would look like this:

```
10-16-18 green
10-17-18 brown
10-18-18 blue
....
10-01-20 purple
```

e.g. the date is 10-16-18 I get an email with "brown" in the body. The file may eventually have hundreds of lines.

Comment: 10-16-18 has "green" on it's line, but you want it to send the text on the next line under it, "brown"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will pull the desired line from the file and return the rest of the line. If more than one line matches it will print all of them.

`` awk '$1 == "'`date '+%m-%d-%y'`'" { print substr($0, 10) }' file.txt | mail ... ``

You could limit to just the first match by adding `;exit` before the `}`.

Also `10` is the length of the match; if you wanted full year you can change the `%y` to `%Y` and `10` to `12`.

So to make a cron job for, say, 6:00am you would put this in your crontab:

`` 0 6 * * * awk '$1 == "'`date '+%m-%d-%y'`'" { print substr($0, 10) }' file.txt | mail -s SUBJECT me@example.com ``

Comment: This was spot on, thank you for a quick and precise answer.